# Compare Mockito enhanced classes against their regular counterparts

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

I've created a simple test class with two fields like

```java
@Mock
private MyTestClass myTestClass;

@Spy
private final MyContext context = CommonTestData.getDefaultContext();
```

Basically I don't really need the spy functionality here, it is just used to automatically inject the object into other mocks.

For the test, I tried to configure `myTestClass` like this:

```java
when(myTestClass.someMethod(eq(context))).thenReturn(someValue);
```

The problem now is, that `Matchers.eq` is *not* matching "un-enhanced" versions of `MyContext`. So when `someMethod` is called during the test with a "regular" instance of `MyContext` that actually `equals` the value used for `context`, the stubbed method is not called.

It seems like the Mockito enhanced `MyContext` class implements its own equals method, at least the equals method of `MyContext` never seems to be called. Thus, I currently can't think of any way to modify the actual comparison being done.

I can think of various workarounds for this issue like using a custom argument matcher or stubbing the method with an instance of the "real" object. I was however wondering: Is there any Mockito-provided solution to check for equality of enhanced classes against their regular counterparts?

Comment: Sure, i‘ll do. I was just hoping that someone else might actually be aware of the correct way to do this ;) But if no one is, maybe it just means there is none...

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is conceptually wrong: the idea of `equals()` in Java is to be **symmetric**: when `a.equals(b)` then you better find that `b.equals(a)`, too!

And in your case, `a` has class MyContext, and `b` has WhateverMockitoSpyDoesToMyContext. So even when the `equals()` of the mockito generated thing works, most likely the other way round, that "base" equals might return `false` (because the original MyContext class knows nothing about potential subclasses like what Mockito is doing here).

I agree that it *might* be convenient to have your example work out, but I am simply not aware of a "correct" way getting there. From that point of view, you actually have to look into use an ArgumentMatcher.

Beyond that: seriously consider if you really gain anything by using `eq()` in the first place. If that check is the "core" of your test, then sure, somehow you better look for clear ways to have that check. But if it is more of a byproduct: then just use `any()` instead.

Meaning: don't make your tests *more* complicated than necessary. Normally, you setup things for one specific case anyway. You only have to *worry* about things passed to `someMethod()` if your code under test could actually, correctly pass different objects to that method.

Comment: You’re absolutely right regarding the `equals` method of course. I was just hoping for something like `Matchers.enhancedEq` to match enhanced and regular objects while stubbing.